# Ignoring part of code after compilation

Tags: c, function, gcc, compilation

My code looks something like this

```
while(!eof)
{
   if(A)
     doSomething;
   if(B)
     doSomething;
}
```

A and B are parameters from comand line. There may be also more parameters. I have struct of Bools, in which are all posible parameters and for every parameter, it determines if he exist or not.

Can i make compiler to not read the some part of the code?

I mean, in this code he will check for existence of B every iteration. What i want to achieve is that he will only check once

```
 if(B)
    doSomething;
```

I want this just to optimalize my program and i NEED to have both ifs in one cycle.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917) first.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "compiler to not read" and "i NEED to have both ifs in one cycle"? Seems contradictory .

Comment: Check the topic of Conditional Compilation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx

Comment: "*if he didnt get parameter B he will never, or max 1 time do*" - What? Please explain

Comment: I think OP wants to check for A and B only once, not every time in main loop.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly speaking, `Ignoring part of code after compilation` makes no sense. The code is already compiled. However. you can skip the *execution* of certain part of code using *conditional statements*, like `if`, `else-if` etc.

FWIW, "Command line parameters" are supplied and considered at *run-time*. There is no way you can decide (conditional compilation) based on that at *compile-time*.

However, if you want, you can always check the *number of arguments* (`argc`) supplied through command line and take action based on that.

Alternatively, if you wanted to have a [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation), reading something about `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` may help.